# Ruby === not acting as it when left-hand argument is a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, comparison-operators

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 3.0.1 and am having a problem whose root cause appears to be the "Array === object" operation.  I saw the same behavior before in a class of my own creation, and programmed around it by not using the "===" operator (I assumed that there was some flaw in my knowledge of Ruby, which is still rather limited).  But now that it is happening inside ActionPack, I need to do something about it.

This surfaced when the FormHelper "fields_for" was not acting the way it should.  The following view code snippet ("<% %>" removed to improve readability):

```
form_for @coupon do |f|
  ...
  f.fields_for @coupon.participants do |cp|
    ...
  end
end
```

gave the error "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class):"
inside the form_for helper method.  I determined that it was executing the wrong branch of a "case" command, set a breakpoint and started testing.  Here are the results:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1152
case record_or_name_or_array
(rdb:1) pp record_or_name_or_array.instance_of? Array
true
(rdb:1) pp Array === record_or_name_or_array
false
(rdb:1) pp Array.object_id
2148267660
(rdb:1) pp record_or_name_or_array.class.object_id
2148267660
```

**This shows pretty definitively that, while "record_or_name_or_array" is definitely an array, "Array === record_or_name_or_array" is returning false.**

BTW, in case you're suspecting that "@f.fields_for" is the wrong syntax, I tried it both with and without the "@f." and got the same result.  I have also restarted RoR and my machine and the results remain unchanged.

Comment: What's the whole code of your case statement?

Comment: Can you include the code from the relevant action of your controller in the question? That might help.

Comment: I did not do so because it did not seem relevant.  The code in my controller is "@coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id])".  The reference is to Coupon.first.participants, where participants is a has_many association.  I have examined participants in the rails console, so I'm reasonably sure that the association works correctly.  Using the debugger I stopped at the point in the helper where the problem occurs, and that is where I'm getting the strange behavior of "CASE record_or_name_or_array WHEN Array" which relies on the === operator.

Comment: @"Kevin Sylvestre" Thanks for the heads up.  My son tells me that most people need to be told this the first time.  That makes him pretty mean for not telling me himself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@coupon = Coupon.last
Array === @coupon.participants #=> false
Array === @coupon.participants.find(:all) #=> true
```

Association `@coupon.participants` is not an array, it is a proxy. The reason why `@coupon.participants.class == Array` is true is described in activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:25

**Added:** Another interesting experiment would be `@coupon.participants.superclass`.

Comment: I'm seeing it now.  The fact that it accepts an array does not mean that it can accept an association expressed as a pseudo-array (e.g. @coupon.participants).  If you want to specify an association, you **must** use the "f.fields_for :participants" syntax.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the console (`rails c`) try running:

```
@coupon = Coupon.last
Array == @coupon.participants
```

If that call returns false, it is most likely that your associations are incorrectly setup (i.e. `has_many :participants` and `belongs_to :coupon`).

Comment: I tried that and it returned true.  I've been looking at the records in participants so I'm reasonably sure the associations are corrrect.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`@coupon.is_a? Array` should return true, `@coupon === Array` would mean `@coupon` was equal to the singleton instance of `Array`

Comment: Remember that the code that is misbehaving is in Rails ActionPack.  The line of code in question is a CASE ... WHEN statement, which reverses the operands so it is testing Array === record_or_name_or_array not the reverse (=== is not commutative).  Any other thoughts?